# solr-index from multiple folders

Tags: solr, indexing

I am trying to make a web search application with solr but I have problems. The problem is that in the example that I followed, all the files are in the same folder. But I want to index files from different directories (ie give the root folder and index all the xml files from all subdirectories). Is that possible?

Comment: you can easily modify the script (post.sh, if you are using it) to iterate and index the files in directory and all its sub directory.

Comment: thank you. Could you please be more specific because I do not know how to do this?Should I use cd?

Comment: In your favorite programming language: **(1)** traverse all directories recursively **(2)** use a HTTP client library (eg: urllib2 for python, curl for shell, libcurl for C) to upload documents to solr.

Answer (score 1):

Try the SimplePostTool recursive option:

```
java -Dauto -Drecursive -jar post.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in a shell script (untested):

```
#!/bin/sh

FILES=$(find . -iname "*.xml")
URL=http://localhost:8983/solr/update

for f in $FILES; do
  echo "Posting $f"
  curl $URL --data-binary @$f -H 'Content-type:application/xml' 
  echo
done

#send the commit command to make sure all the changes are flushed and visible
curl $URL --data-binary '<commit/>' -H 'Content-type:application/xml'
echo
```

Place it in the root folder where you have the xml files.

(i assume you have linux and the 'post.sh' script is the example you followed)